# get selected checked value from patosai tree multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Im trying to get value from checkbox that has been checked, but for some reason the value is shuffled in some weird pattern

here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htumxL5r/14/) (try to check fruit and then click disable)

```
<input id="checkedTree" type="text"/>
<select id="test-select" onchange="getCheckedTree()">
  <option value="1" data-section="fruit">Banana</option>
  <option value="2" data-section="fruit">Apple</option>
  <option value="3" data-section="fruit">Avocado</option>
  <option value="4" data-section="fruit">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="5" data-section="fruit">PenPineappleApplePen</option>
  <option value="6" data-section="animal">Tiger</option>
  <option value="7" data-section="animal">Lion</option>
  <option value="8" data-section="animal">Pitbull</option>
  <option value="9" data-section="animal">OrangUtan</option>
  <option value="10" data-section="animal">Marsupilami Yellow cartoon</option>
</select>
```

I need to know why is it happened, and how to fix it. i do know the other way to get proper value [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/htumxL5r/9/). But for my project case i need "for" method

Update 1-> update jsfiddle

Comment: why you are doing this much code when you have already a working code ?

Comment: Because i need to disabled some checked box if the value is match with database therefore i need "for method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values shuffled because you are getting the input array index `checkedText.value = selectobject[z].value;` knowing that at the change event the order of your hidden inputs change which causes the wrong values . (you can check by setting test-select display :block after page loding )

Above a working snippet :

note that you can passe directly value (1,2,3.. ) to the checkedTree input to disable directly inputs .

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $select = $('#test-select');
  $select.treeMultiselect({ 
        enableSelectAll: true,
        sortable: false, 
        searchable: true,
        startCollapse: true
    });
  
});

  
function getCheckedTree(){
    var tempCtr=0;
    var $checkedText = $("#checkedTree");

    var selectobject = $("[id*=treemultiselect-0-]:checked");
    $checkedText.val("");
    for(i=0;i<selectobject.length;i++) {
      if(tempCtr==0){
        tempCtr=1;
        $checkedText.val($(selectobject[i]).parent().data("value"));
      }else{
        $checkedText.val($checkedText.val() + $(selectobject[i]).parent().data("value"));
      }
    }
  }
  function funcDis(){
      var $checkedText = $("#checkedTree");
      if($checkedText.val().length>0) {
       $checkedText.val().split("").forEach(function(val){
         $(".tree-multiselect .item[data-value="+val+"] input").prop('disabled', true);
         $("#test-select option[value="+val+"]").prop('disabled', true);
        })
      };

  }
  
  function enableAll(){
   $(".tree-multiselect input").each(function(idx){
     $(this).prop('disabled', false);
      var val = $(this).parent().data("value");
      $("#test-select option[value="+val+"]").prop('disabled', false);
    })
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/patosai/tree-multiselect/v2.1.3/dist/jquery.tree-multiselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/patosai/tree-multiselect/v2.1.3/dist/jquery.tree-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<input id="checkedTree" type="text"/> <button onclick="funcDis()">disable</button><button onclick="enableAll()">enable all</button>
<select id="test-select" onchange="getCheckedTree()">
  <option value="1" data-section="fruit">Banana</option>
  <option value="2" data-section="fruit">Apple</option>
  <option value="3" data-section="fruit">Avocado</option>
  <option value="4" data-section="fruit">Pineapple</option>
  <option value="5" data-section="fruit">PenPineappleApplePen</option>
  <option value="6" data-section="animal">Tiger</option>
  <option value="7" data-section="animal">Lion</option>
  <option value="8" data-section="animal">Pitbull</option>
  <option value="9" data-section="animal">OrangUtan</option>
  <option value="10" data-section="animal">Marsupilami Yellow cartoon</option>
</select>
```

PS:You  can pass dirctly an array of value to funcDis and disable input at start up .

That's all ,I [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/htumxL5r/15/) if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @bRIMOs, But how can i add if(checked[$ctr].checked=true){append to textbox}else{do not append}. Since in your code, if i disable banana and check fruit i still get banana value. Here new jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/htumxL5r/16/

Comment: Hey @AlexanderChandra , I' have managed to make your demand 
please see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/htumxL5r/17/)